# Перевести Js в JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот код который при перемещение ползунка добавляет картинку, мне надо перевести его на JQuery. Помогите пожайлуста.

```
function funVolume() {
    var rng = document.getElementById('r1'); //rng - это Input
    var p = document.getElementById('one'); // span - span
    var vol_3 = document.getElementsByClassName('vol_3');
    var value = rng.value;
    if(value < 50) {
        p.innerHTML = "<img style='margin: 7px -4px 0 0' src ='img/vol_2.png'>";
    }
    else if (value > 50) {
        p.innerHTML = "<img style='margin: 7px -4px 0 0' src ='img/vol_2.png'><img style='margin: 3px 0 0 0' src ='img/vlo_3.png'>";
    }
    if(value < 1){
        p.innerHTML = " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `getElementById` = `$("#id")` и `getElementsByClassName` = `$(".class")`, а также `innerHTML ` = `$(elem).html('что-то');`

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Что, если value===50?

Comment: @vp_arth, _ничего_ - Очевидно

Answer (score 1):

```js
// вариант с вашего примера
function funVolume() {
  var rng = $('#r1'); //rng - это Input
  var p = $('#one'); // span - span
  var vol_3 = $('.vol_3');
  var value = rng.val();
  
  if (value < 50) {
    p.html("<img style='margin: 7px -4px 0 0' src ='img/vol_2.png'>");
  } else if (value > 50) {
    p.html("<img style='margin: 7px -4px 0 0' src ='img/vol_2.png'><img style='margin: 3px 0 0 0' src ='img/vlo_3.png'>");
  }
  if (value < 1) {
    p.html("");
  }
}  

// но лучше сделать так:
function funVolume() {
  var p = $('#one'); // span - span
  var value = $('#r1').val(); // получаем значание поля Input
  
  switch (true) {
    case (value < 1):
      p.html("");
      break;
    case (value < 50):
      p.html("<img style='margin: 7px -4px 0 0' src ='img/vol_2.png'>");
      break;
    case (value > 50):
      p.html("<img style='margin: 7px -4px 0 0' src ='img/vol_2.png'><img style='margin: 3px 0 0 0' src ='img/vlo_3.png'>");
      break;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде всё так, сам только изучаю =)
Поправил немного

```
function funVolume() {       
    if ( $('#r1').val() < 50 ) {
        $('#one').html("<img style='margin: 7px -4px 0 0' src ='img/vol_2.png'>");
    } else if ( $('#r1').val() > 50  ) {
        $('#one').html("<img style='margin: 7px -4px 0 0' src ='img/vol_2.png'><img style='margin: 3px 0 0 0' src ='img/vlo_3.png'>");        
    }
    if ( $('#r1').val() < 1 ) {
        $('#one').html(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: сейчас буду крутить)

Answer (score 0):

Точный ответ:

```
function funVolume() {
    let rng = $('#r1'); //rng - это Input
    let p = $('#one'); // span - span
    let vol_3 = $('.vol_3');
    let value = rng.val();
    if(value < 50) {
        p.html("<img style='margin: 7px -4px 0 0' src ='img/vol_2.png'>");
    }
    else if (value > 50) {
        p.html("<img style='margin: 7px -4px 0 0' src ='img/vol_2.png'><img style='margin: 3px 0 0 0' src ='img/vlo_3.png'>");
    }
    if(value < 1){
        p.html("");
    }
}
```

Comment: РАБОТАЕТ, спасибо!

Comment: Обращайся;) и отмечай ответ как правильный :)

Answer (score -1):

```
function funVolume() {
  var value = $('#r1').val();
  if (value < 1) $('#one').empty();
  else ($('#one').html(value < 50 
                                  ?"<img style='margin: 7px -4px 0 0' src ='img/vol_2.png'>" 
                                  :"<img style='margin: 7px -4px 0 0' src ='img/vol_2.png'><img style='margin: 3px 0 0 0' src ='img/vlo_3.png'>"
                       );
}
```